# batch multi-condition if else ==batch==

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, conditional-statements, move

I would like to know how to use multicondition if else. For example I am looking 
if the folder (A) exists then move it to another folder (B)
else if the folder (B) exists then move it to another folder (A) else msg * no such directry

code:

```
if exist ( C:\Users\%username%\AppData\ABC\
taskkill /f /im File.exe 
move C:\Users\%username%\ABC C:\Windows\system\ABC2\
msg * Move 
exit
 ) else if exist ( C:\Windows\system\Cool\
taskkill /f /im Viber.exe
move C:\Windows\system\Cool C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\ViberPC\
msg * You will active your viber thank you Enjoy it baby. i love you all 
exit
 ) else ( 
msg * This account (number) does not exist please singup on your smartphone to get acces thank you ... have a nice day
 ) )
pause
```

Comment: Why are you using a parentheses after the IF EXIST?

Comment: I found it in that forum and when i use it without parenthese nothing happend ... my problem is i get the msg but the folder still in desktop!! it does not move or when i delet it by my self it didnt show last msg

Comment: The parentheses should be after the folder your checking for existance.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems with this code. First off, `msg` is not a batch command. Try `echo` instead. Next, the path for the `exist` statement must come before the parenthesis. There is also an unnecessary parenthesis at the end, and lastly, the `pause` at the end of the code will only work if the `else` statement is true, since `exit` exits the script itself, not the nested statements. The fixed code is bellow.

```
if exist C:\Users\%username%\AppData\ABC\ (
taskkill /f /im File.exe 
move C:\Users\%username%\ABC C:\Windows\system\ABC2\
echo * Move 
) else if exist C:\Windows\system\Cool\ (
taskkill /f /im Viber.exe
move C:\Windows\system\Cool C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\ViberPC\
echo * You will active your viber thank you Enjoy it baby. i love you all 
) else ( 
echo * This account (number) does not exist please singup on your smartphone to get acces thank you ... have a nice day
)
pause
```

There are also some spelling errors. I left them in case they where intentional.

Comment: echo use to show result on batch command but i need to run this script silently so msg only will apear ;) thanks for your answer i just forget mkdir C:\Windows\system\ABC2  have nice day

Answer (score 0):

The following sample show you the [`IF`](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html) [syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-brackets.html)

```
@echo off
if exist ABC (
  echo "ABC" exist
) else if exist Cool (
  echo "ABC" doesn't exist but "Cool" exist  
) else (
  echo "ABC" nor "Cool" exists.
)
pause
```

---

One last thing, in `echo` command you have to [escape](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) brackets.

```
@echo off
if exist C:\Users\%username%\AppData\ABC\nul (
  taskkill /f /im File.exe 
  move C:\Users\%username%\ABC C:\Windows\system\ABC2\
  echo Move done
) else if exist C:\Windows\system\Cool\nul (
  taskkill /f /im Viber.exe
  move C:\Windows\system\Cool C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\ViberPC\
  echo You will active your viber thank you Enjoy it baby. i love you all 
) else ( 
  echo This account ^(number^) does not exist,
  echo please sign up on your smart phone to get access
  echo Thank you. Have a nice day.
)
pause
```